# JavaScript - Split CSV, trim spaces, remove backslash - result is an array of strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex, csv

Is there a better way to do the following?
What I want is to be able to split a CSV, trim space(s), and remove backslash(es) - and store into an array.
Since I've got jQuery already in my project, using that is fine if appropriate for an answer.

```js
var vehicleText = " Hyundai Sonata\\ , Ford Windstar , Mazda B2300 , Chevy Cavalier ";

var cleanVehicles = vehicleText.split(/\s*,\s*/);
var arr2 = []
$.each(cleanVehicles, function(idx, val) {
  arr2.push(val.replace(/\\/g, ''));
});

$("#result").text(arr2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">original text</div>
```

Comment: You are doing a good job. You can also use `map()` function instead of `each`. Like `var arr2 = $.map(cleanVehicles, function(val) {
        return val.replace(/\\/g, '');
    });`

Comment: If it's working what is point of question? Better place for questions like this is http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: how would you go about having escaped content containing a comma? :) How good can you control the content of the csv? Maybe such a plugin can help: https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv